# Instruction Counter made with FRIDA Stalker

Tags: python, counter, dbi, instrumentation, frida

I want to build a simple frida script that have to count the instructions executed by a process (/bin/ls in this case). There is my code

```
import frida
import sys

def on_message(message, data):
    print(message)
    global c
    c += 1

stalker="""
    Stalker.follow(Process.getCurrentThreadId(),
    {
        events: {call: true, exec: true, ret: false},

        onCallSummary: function (summary) {
            send(summary);
        }
    });
"""


c = 0
pid = frida.spawn(['/bin/ls'])
process = frida.attach(pid)

script = process.create_script(stalker)
script.on('message', on_message)
script.load()
print(c)
```

I increment a global counter on receaving any message, that is generated by Frida-Stalker, but when I print the counter, the result is 0.

Any idea? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looking at your code I am missing a `frida.resume(pid)` after loading your script. Without that the `ls` process will just wait indefinitely doing nothing.

Comment: Oh, right! Sorry but I'm pretty new to Frida. Now this script return "1", but in reality more than one instruction is executed.. (I tested whit **Pin** and **DynamoRIO**). Do you know where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues:

1. both your script and the process finish before Stalker can send its accumulated data to the callbacks
2. When you start stalking (I think) you are in the frida setup process and not in the Thread that eventually executes the binary (it hasn’t yet been started)

To work around (1) and have the python script wait, I added:

```py
    frida.resume(pid)
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

To give Stalker time to finish, I hooked `exit` (Not sure if there isn’t a better way to delay program exit, maybe a signal could be trapped instead).

```js
    Interceptor.attach(Module.getExportByName(null, "exit"), {
      onEnter(args) {
        Stalker.flush();
        Thread.sleep(.1);
      }
    });
```

Prior art for (2) includes https://github.com/WorksButNotTested/stalker-coverage.

It mentions that `Interceptor.attach` has issues when combined with Stalker, so instead I replace the original `__libc_start_main`.

Here’s the full working js code: https://gist.github.com/rumpeltux/b626eabe7ee1a9c0528434b7afe156be